# Вложение тега <a> в теги <h1>-<h6>

Tags: html

```
<h4 class="my-2"><a href="#">Пример</a></h4>
```

Можно ли делать так? Правильно ли это? Если нет, то как исправить?

Comment: Валидатор не ругается — значит правильно

Comment: В html5 даже такой вариант будет валидным <a href="#"><h4 class="my-2">Пример</h4></a>

Comment: строчный в блочном, все правильно, все валидно

Comment: тег h4 (блочный) - в тег а (строчный) - тоже валидно

Answer (score 0):

Согласно описанию заголовочных элементов в разделе ([Спецификация HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements))

```
4.3.6. The h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 elements
```

их модель содержания определяется следующим образом

```
Content model: 
Phrasing content.
```

Модель содержания описывает, какое содержание может быть включено в качестве дочерних элементов данного элемента

> Content model 
>   A normative description of what content must be included
>   as children and descendants of the element.

Phrasing content определяется следующим образом

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that
>   mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level

и в состав этих элементов входит элемент `<a>`.

Следовательно заголовочные элементы `<h1>,...,<h6>` могут включать в себя элементы `<a>` в качестве дочерних элементов.